array in ascending and descending order in C# using LINQ
In this i have write two linq queries

For Ascending order
For Descending order

i have done this in one way can you guy's suggest me to the another method for knowledge if exists.
Here is the code
// Specify the data source.
int [] scores = [79,92,98,2];

// Define the query expression for ascending order.
IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery = from score in scores orderby score ascending select score;

// Define the query expression for descending order.
var scoreQueryDesc = from score in scores orderby score descending select score;

// Execute the ascending query 
foreach (var i in scoreQuery)
{
        Console.Write(i + " ");
}

// This Console is for Next line.
Console.WriteLine();

// Execute the descending query 
foreach (var i in scoreQueryDesc)
{
        Console.Write(i + " ");
}

In the above code i have define value in two type's

IEnumerable scoreQuery
var scoreQueryDesc

Please suggest me there is any other approach to do this

What are you actually trying to do? You need both or you need just one order direction?

If you have the array sorted in one direction, you can have the opposite direction in-place simply by traversing the array from end-to-front. If efficiency is relevant, then that can save you both time and memory.

@Fildor: but of course he needs to create a new array because the original is not ordered

@TimSchmelter Ok I should have been clearer: "If you have the array sorted in one direction" should have been "Once you have ..."

If you want to conditionally sort ascending or descending, you could use this extension:
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> sequence,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    bool descending)
{
    return descending
        ? sequence.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
        : sequence.OrderBy(keySelector);
}

Then your code becomes simple:
bool descending = true; // can be set at runtime
IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery = scores.OrderByWithDirection(i => i, descending);


I would go with an enum rather than a bool. Seeing scores.OrderByWithDirection(i => i, true); versus scores.OrderByWithDirection(i => i, Direction.Ascending); would be far better.

@Enigmativity: true, but it should give the idea, he can pass the bool directly to the method or map to an enum which he needs to create first.

@Enigmativity Or just use a named parameter descending: true. Also we can add .Order(bool descending) as another extension, without a selector.

@Charlieface - descending: true is optional, but Direction.Descending is explicit and required.

You can now write this:
int[] scores = [79, 92, 98, 2];

IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery = scores.Order();

var scoreQueryDesc = scores.OrderDescending();

